# Open set in the image of a dominant morphism of affine spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an infinite field, $X=Y=\mathbb{A}^n_k$, and let $\varphi:X\longrightarrow Y$ be defined by $n$ algebraically independent polynomials. In particular, $\varphi$ is dominant (that is, $\varphi(X)$ is a dense subset of $Y$).

Now, using Noether normalisation, one usually proves that there is a non-empty open subset $U\subseteq\varphi(X)$. I wonder how large $U$ could be. Note that in the proof, $U$ is a principal open set.

Can we hope for a better bound than $\dim(Y\setminus U)\leq n-1$ in general?

EDIT. The field $k$ should be algebraically closed; otherwise, the statement is not true at all.

Comment: Have you considered when $n=1$?

Comment: I have just noticed that $k$ has to be algebraically closed, otherwise we might not have any non-empty open set contained in the image. Take for example $k=\mathbb{Q}$, $n=1$ and $\varphi(x)=x^2$. On the other hand, the case $n=1$ is trivial, for then $\varphi$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

If by a better bound you mean whether $\dim(Y \setminus U) \le n - 2$ in general, then the answer is no. The polynomials $x$ and $xy$ are algebraically independent (over $\mathbb{C}$), and the morphism $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C}$ sending $(x,y) \mapsto (x,xy)$ is such that the complement of the image is $1$-dimensional (in this case, $Y \setminus U$ consists of the $y$-axis with the origin removed).

Comment: Indeed. However, we have $\dim(Y\setminus U)\leq 1$ now. Is it possible (though highly unlikely) that we have a bound independently of $n$ in general?